# How do I say "fond of"?

Tags: traduction, anglais, vocabulaire, expressions

If I wish to say "I was very fond of ... ", how would I say this? A quick internet search told me that most people tend to use "aimais", but that gives me the impression that "I liked" or "I loved". Is there any other way of expressing the above statement?

Comment: It depends on the context. Is it food? A person? Something else? The answer will change...

Comment: Adding “bien” after “aimer” to get “J’aimais bien.. ” in your case, seems to temper the “love” aspect of “aimer” in French, but it might get it all the way down to “like,” & I get that you want to say something that’s between “love” and “like.” As @NajibIdrissi correctly points out it fully depends on the context because whereas “aimer” all alone would be fine in certain contexts, “aimer bien”=(j'aimais bien) or “aimer beaucoup”=(j'aimais beaucoup) would be better in others. There might be another, non-"aimer" word that works in multiple contexts, but I'm not a native speaker & I don't know it

Comment: French is the language of love, of course! The various shades of like/fond/love one finds in English are all basically "aimer" in French. Je l'aime tout!

Comment: That's an interesting way to think of it @GregHewgill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean "I was very fond of ..." an activity then you can say "J'étais très féru de ..." or more commonly "J'aimais beaucoup ..."

Comment: "I was fond of" means "j'affectionnais".

Answer (score -2):

You also use "j'apprécie beaucoup..."

Comment: Les deux expressions n'ont pas du tout le même sens. Certes, *fond of* a une gamme large de sens suivant le contexte, mais « j'adore », c'est trop fort.

Comment: I agree with @Gilles, adorer is a very strong word to use in this context

Comment: Yes "j'adore" is almost as strong as I worship. Always depends on the context

Answer (score -3):

A simple formula would be ***amoureux, -euse de***.

The root is *amour*.

Comment: “*Fond of*”, c'est plus proche de *aimer bien*. Dans la plupart des contextes, *amoureux* serait un contresens.

Comment: Yes, as @Gilles said, amoureux gives the impression of something along the lines of a romantic lover.